# Filtering Endpoint

Tags: javascript, express, backend, filtering

I am building a filtering API for filtering my properties. I have made multiple datasets for my properties which I have separated like below;

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS properties;
CREATE TABLE properties(
  property_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int,
  property_type_id int, 
  property_status_id int,
  description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  size_sq_meters DECIMAL(10, 2),
  price int NOT NULL,
  no_of_rooms int NOT NULL,
  no_of_bedrooms int NOT NULL,
  no_of_bathrooms int NOT NULL,
  listed_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (property_type_id) REFERENCES property_types(property_type_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (property_status_id) REFERENCES property_statuses(property_status_id)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS property_types;
CREATE TABLE property_types(
  property_type_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  property_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS property_statuses;
CREATE TABLE property_statuses(
  property_status_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  property_status VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

What I want to do is write an endpoint that would allow users to select the values inside the properties when they are searching for their properties as parameters and give the matching properties as results. I am using an **express** framework called **xest** which separates your controllers, actions, and SQL queries into separate folders. The documentation can be found here: https://xestjs.com/docs/

This is what I got so far (only trying to use location, price and property_type(from a separate table) as parameters ;

```
router.get(
  "/properties/filter/:location/:price/:propertyType",
  **getFilterProperty**
);
```

The controller, getFilterProperty;

```
const fetchFilterProperty = require("~root/actions/properties/fetchFilterProperty");
const handleAPIError = require("~root/utils/handleAPIError");

const getFilterProperty = async (req, res) => {
  const { location, price, propertyType } = req.params;
  try {
    const { filteredResult } = await fetchFilterProperty()({
      location,
      price,
      propertyType
    });
    res.status(201).send({
      filteredResult
    });
  } catch (err) {
handleAPIError(res, err);
 }
};
 module.exports = getFilterProperty;
```

Action, FetchFilterProperty;

```
const selectFilterProperty = require("./queries/selectFilterProperty");

const fetchFilterProperty = async ({ location, price, propertyType }) => {
  const filteredResult = await selectFilterProperty({
    location,
    price,
    propertyType
  });

  return { filteredResult };
};

module.exports = fetchFilterProperty;
```

The query selectFilterProperty;

```
const { submitQuery, camelKeys } = require("~root/lib/database");

const selectFilterProperty = ({ location, price, propertyType }) => submitQuery`
SELECT
    properties.location,
    properties.price,
    property_types.property_type,
FROM
    properties
JOIN 
    property_types ON properties.property_type_id = property_types.property_type_id 
WHERE
    properties.location = ${location} AND
    properties.price = ${price} AND
    property_types.property_type = ${propertyType}`;

module.exports = camelKeys(selectFilterProperty);
```

I am not sure how to use .filter to filter results based on user parameters, let alone able to fetch property_types or property_statuses from separate property tables, although I believe I am close. Any help with writing my filtering API would be greatly appreciated. You can also write the endpoint in standard Express which I can hopefully convert it for my framework.

Thanks in advance
(Sorry for the long question)